# Llamado de funciones de conexión entre paginas en php

Tags: php, html5, web

Cordial saludo espero se encuentre muy bien, el objeto de la presente es el de solicitar su ayuda en el siguiente inconveniente:
Tengo un archivo de conexión con nombre database.php, que está dentro de una carpeta que se llama Conexión.
El código database.php, es el siguiente:

```
<?php
class Database{

private $host;
private $db;
private $user;
private $password;
private $charset;

public function __construct(){
   $this->host='localhost:127.0.0.1:3306';
      $this->db='grupo4sas';
      $this->user='root';
      $this->password='';
      $this->charset='utf8mb4';   /* opcional no entiendo por que este user*/
}   

function connect(){
 try{
  $connection = "mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db . ";charset=" . $this->charset;
  $options = [ 
     PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
     PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
   ];

$pdo= new PDO($connection, $this->password, $options);
return $pdo;
}catch(PDOException $e){
  print_r('Error connection: ' . $e->getMessage()); 
}
}
}
?>
```

Tengo otro archivo en donde tengo un combobox,el archivo se llama apartamentos.php, cuyo código es el siguiente:

```
 <div id="derecha">
        <tr>
           <?php
            require ('Conexion/database.php');
            connect();  //Aquí llamo a la función connect(); del archivo database.php 
           $query = "SELECT nombreproy FROM apartamentos INNER JOIN proyectos ON 
           apartamentos.nombreproy=proyectos.nombreproy ORDER BY nombreproy";
           $resultado=$connection->query($query);
           ?>
          <div>Seleccione nombre del proyecto: <select name="cbx_nombreproy"  
          id="cbx_nombreproy">
            <option value="0">Seleccione nombre del proyecto</option>
        <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['nombreproy']; ?>"><?php echo $row['nombreproy'];   
        ?>
          </option>
         ?php } ?>
        </select></div> 
        </tr> 
    </div>
```

Pero al ejecutar el aplicativo, me muestra el siguiente error:

Notice: Undefined variable: connection in C:\wamp64\www\Grupo4sas\Apartamentos.php on line 54

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\wamp64\www\Grupo4sas\Apartamentos.php on line 54

El código que tengo en la línea 54 es:

```
  $resultado=$connection->query($query);
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 1):

**Database** al ser una clase tienes que instanciarla primero

En la línea 54 escribe lo siguiente:

```
$connection = new Database;

$resultado=$connection->query($query);
```

Comment: Así no funcionará, deberá llamar a `connect()` que es quien devuelve una instancia de la conexión. Por ejemplo: `$db = new Database; $pdo=$db->connect();` Y luego: `$resultado=$pdo->query($query);`

Comment: A.Cedano muchas gracias ,el código lo modifique de la siguiente manera:               
<?php require ('Conexion/database.php'); connect();$query ="SELECT ..";                                                                                                               $db=new Database;$pdo=$db->connect();$resultado=$pdo->query($query);?>  pero me muestra los siguientes errores:Fatal error:Uncaught Error:Call to undefined function connect() in C:\wamp64\www\Grupo4sas\Apartamentos.php on line51 y Error: Call to undefined function connect()in C:\wamp64\www\Grupo4sas\Apartamentos.php on line51

Comment: @MartínHernández perdón, cometí un error al crear la instancia (me faltaron los paréntesis `()`). Ponlo así: `$db = new Database(); $pdo=$db->connect();` y ya luego usa `$pdo` para invocar a `query()`. Por cierto, el `connect()` que tienes más arriba, debes quitarlo, de lo contrario estarías llamando dos veces a la conexión sin necesidad. La idea aquí es que en la variable `$pdo` guardarás una referencia a la conexión para poder usarla cuando la necesites.